# Name of the game where you are a monk collecting scriptures and could become pope?

Tags: identify-this-game

I trying to recall the title of a game. I remember its gameplay and mechanics rather well, however its name eludes me.

- The premise has you as monks who travel around Italy during the
  medieval period, reconstructing holy books. There's a pretty detailed map drawn in the Medieval style which serves as the game board. Edit: Actually the premise is that you are monks trying to construct a common language from analyzing dialects from different part of Italy to come up with a common form of the language.
- It uses Action Points system, when you spend 1 AP to move to one
  neighboring province,  3 AP to move two. You can also use AP to
  gather money. The AP tokens are big purple tokens. You can spend some
  AP to unlock more AP.
- You are supposed to go to different part of the maps to reconstruct
  books from the different pieces.
- Towards the end of the game, the Pope will die and one of the players
  could become Pope depending on certain conditions.
- Name of the game is in Latin

Comment: As a videogamer, I am amazed by the game mechanic and disappointed that this question is not on Arqade.

Comment: Which is why I love board games, because there's such an amazing variety of interesting premises.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After hunting through various BoardGameGeek lists, I had the idea of looking for games set in Italy (there's actually [a list](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/211408/boardgames-set-italy/page/9) for that!). The game in question is [De Vulgari Eloquentia](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/75165/de-vulgari-eloquentia).